# Subdomain redirects to a given virtual directory in IIS

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, iis-7, subdomain

I have a domain where I have created several subdomains. I manage to alter the DNS records, so a given subdomain redirects to a different server. For example?

```
app.domain.com -> 123.45.66.11
```

Now, my app is an ASP.NET MVC app responding to the following URL 123.45.66.11/app. How do I configure IIS, that the url

```
http://app.domain.com -> 123.45.66.11/app
```

points to my virtual directory app instead of the root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of IIS are you running?  You'll need to setup host headers to accomplish what you want to do.

IIS 6
http://microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/883a9544-3f70-4d46-a6df-bbadbd1fe7de.mspx?mfr=true

IIS 7
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: @Micheal I am running IIS7 and I could not find the settings there. Thanks for the links

Comment: The IIS 7 link is not working for me.

Comment: I had to add a new site in IIS7 with a new host header and then point it to my web app. It is now working perfectly.

Comment: One link is spam, and another is broken.  Another reason primarily link based answers are bad.

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS Manager right click on *Sites*, and choose *Add Web Site...*
In the opened window:

1. Choose a name for your application and write it under *Site name*
2. Push the *Select...* button near the *Application pool* and choose *ASP.NET v4.0*
3. Under *Physical path* browse for the web-app location (usually under c:\inetpub\wwwroot...). 
   Remark: Usually when I push *Test Settings...* it doesn't work. But still the hole process  works. So just be patient and keep tracking.
4. In the *Binding* all you need to insert is your subdomain name (app.domain.com) under *Host name*.
5. Push OK

That's it!
Enjoy your new subdomain address :-)